# Fail Webdriver test if element is present

Tags: testing, selenium, web, webdriver

I'm new to Webdriver and I'm wondering how do I make my test case fail if an element is present. Using the following code I can send an output that if the element id `errorMessages` is present an output will be displayed. Is there anyway I can make the test fail also?

```
if (driver.findElements(By.id("errorMessages")).size() != 0) {
    System.out.println("Error..Warning Subscriber already exists ");
}
```

Comment: Are you using JUnit?

Comment: I' currently using TestNG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With TestNG you can simply use `Assert.fail("your message");` inside the `if` block to mark the test as failed. Something like:

```
if (driver.findElements(By.id("errorMessages")).size() != 0) {
   Assert.fail("Error..Warning Subscriber already exists ");    
}
```

See [this](http://testng.org/doclava/reference/org/testng/Assert.html) for overloading

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking at it in the wrong way. Rather than checking if the size is what you expect and then forcing the test to fail, use the inbuilt assertion methods so it reads much more like a logical statement:

```
assertTrue(driver.findElements(By.id("errorMessages")).size() == 0, "Error..Warning Subscriber already exists");
```

[Documentation from the TestNG site](http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/Assert.html#assertTrue(boolean,%20java.lang.String))

The inbuilt assertion methods will then print out that message if that assertion fails.